# How can I pass column and table name as parameters to a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIdFromNameParameter 
    (columnName VARCHAR2, tableName VARCHAR2, whereColumn VARCHAR2, parameterColumn VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    idCatc VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'SELECT ' || columnName || ' INTO ' || idCatc || ' FROM ' || tableName || ' WHERE ' || whereColumn || ' = ' ||  parameterColumn;
    RETURN idCatc;
END;
/
```

I get this warning:

> Warning: Function created with compilation errors

Comment: Regardless of the solution you choose , please please ensure you are not enabling SQL Injection. Scrub all inputs. Use binds.

Comment: @KrisRice can u explain more

Comment: Why not just pass in a full sql statement at this point? There's already no sql injection protection.

Comment: Mobile right now. I’ll post a longer example later when I have a keyboard.

Comment: Looks like the real question was _"How can I use dynamic SQL to return a value?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a function like this, ensure it's safe from sql injection with something like the following. This uses dbms_assert to sanitize the inputs against thing like ';drop table xyz;'

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getidfromnameparameter (
        in_columnname        VARCHAR2,
        in_tablename         VARCHAR2,
        in_wherecolumn       VARCHAR2,
        in_parametercolumn   VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
        idcatc   VARCHAR2(50);
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '
                         || sys.dbms_assert.qualified_sql_name(in_columnName)
                         || ' FROM '
                         || sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name(in_tableName)
                         || ' WHERE '
                         || sys.dbms_assert.qualified_sql_name(in_whereColumn)
                         || ' = '
                         || sys.dbms_assert.enquote_literal(in_parametercolumn)
       INTO idcatc;

       RETURN idcatc;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: it's work good 
how  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE work with OPEN curosr FOR SELECT ...

Comment: I cannot use this to get an entire column.  Is there a way to make the output multi-valued?

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, the `into` is part of `execute immediate`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIdFromNameParameter (
    in_columnName VARCHAR2,
    in_tableName VARCHAR2,
    in_whereColumn VARCHAR2,
    in_parameterColumn VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    idCatc VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'SELECT ' || in_columnName || ' FROM ' || in_tableName || ' WHERE ' || in_whereColumn || ' = ' ||  in_parameterColumn
    INTO idCatc;
    RETURN idCatc;
END;
```

You were also using `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: this is also work
 'execute immediate 'SELECT ' || columnName || ' INTO ' || idCatc || ' FROM ' || tableName || ' WHERE ' || whereColumn || ' = ' ||  parameterColumn;'

Comment: `execute immediate 'SELECT ' || in_columnName || ' FROM ' || in_tableName || ' WHERE ' || in_whereColumn || ' = :par' INTO idCatc using in_parameterColumn;` would be even better.